# Precision selection for Intel's Short Vector Math Library (SVML) functions?

Tags: assembly, naming-conventions, vectorization, intel, intel-mkl

I'm interested in knowing the meaning of the naming conventions for Intel's SVML function symbols.

Indeed, it seems that each function of the SVML has a quite wide variety of core functions (one of which gets chosen and called at runtime) but I don't succeed in accessing all of them at runtime on my machine for unknown reasons. I have tried many compilation options such as the target accuracy, or the architecture the code was compiled and optimized against. Each time I run my program the chosen core function is the one with the suffix `_h9`, e.g. `__svml_logf4_h9`

I'd like to know the purposes of other core functions such as those ending in `_br`, `_e7`, `_ep`, `_ex` and `_ha` and how I could actually manage to have these codes run on my machine.

[EDIT in response to @zam]
I don't expect it either to be standardized. Your suggestion about _ha and _br suffixes makes much sense now! Yet those suffixes are in the global text (code) section, and call a runtime-chosen subroutine in the local text section, e.g. `_br` might chose the `_br_ex` or the `_br_h9` subroutine, one of which is VEX-encoded (_h9) whereas the other is not.
From what you said, I now guess that `_ex` and `_ep` stand for different processor families, e.g. the Broadwell-EX family.
All `_h9` routines are VEX-encoded, so I guess they relate to AVX somehow, but then why is `_br_ex` *not* VEX-encoded while a Broadwell-EX CPU such as the Xeon E7 v4 does feature AVX instructions?

Comment: I would expect it to be non-standardized proprietary info. From common sense I would also expect h standing for Haswell and br for Broadwell. How do you want to use this knowledge? Do you want to check whenever wrong version has been invoked resulting in low performance or what?

Comment: I want to compare their performances and accuracy. I'll edit my post to add info about what I've learned from your comment.

Comment: I'd like to be able to chose a routine with a given accuracy as with the option -fimf-precision={low,medium,high} or -fimf-max-error={#ulps}, but currently this option achieves nothing on my machine, although its in my ICC's man page. Perhaps this is only for libimf and not libsvml but it is not clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: Regarding precision compilation switches: SVML behavior is most consistent when you use OpenMP4.x simd/declare simd loops and kernels. If you only use auto-vectorization (no pragmas), there are could be extra restrictions (language complience, cost model, etc), which may prohibit compilers from using "most desirable" versions. I could also imagine (but it's not the case at least with fresh Intel compilers) the opposite: OpenMP4.x semantics indirectly influencing precision, being higher priority than flags.

Comment: In response to your updated question: do you say there is really _br_ep version as well? I could also imagine that for every platform there is SSE-enabled and AVX-enabled versions to be used depending on -xAVX/-mAVX compilation flags presence/absence (and the same for other ISA variants). To make it clear - I'm not MKL/SVML developer, therefore I should not know precise answer even if I have indirect info; but I have some experience with SVML and i know that SVML prefixes are not documented for sure and some aspects of these things could be intentionally hidden by vendor.

Comment: I actually use the SVML intrinsics headers, present in `immintrin.h`, to call the routines. E.g. for `logf4` I call `_mm_log_ps`.
As far as I can tell, no, there is no _br_ep subroutine, only _br_ex and _br_h9.
Further investigation showed that CPUID is used to help chose the "right" subroutine at runtime, so I guess I might as well look for other machines to run the binary and see which routine gets called. I now expect the routines to have the same accuracy although they use different evaluation schemes (polynomials and range reductions are sometimes different).

Comment: For information, a desktop computer running with a Sandy Bridge CPU (without AVX) calls the subroutine `_e7` which is the same as `_h9` but not VEX-encoded.